# O que significa o operador ^= no C#?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, operadores

Possuo uma função no C#, onde eu descriptografo uma *string* e preciso converter em uma função no SQL Server para os técnicos conseguirem trabalhar com o valor descriptografado.

Existe um *foreach*, que não entendo como funciona:

```
var calculoChave = 0;
foreach (var c in chave)
{
    calculoChave ^= c;
}
```

O que significa este  "^=", e o que ele faz?

Debugando o código, eu percebi que quando a chave possui um número, ele soma com 48. Igual, se a chave for igual a 3, o valor do calculo chave será 51. Se a chave possuir mais de 2 números, muda o cálculo, e não achei um sequência lógica para isso.

Comment: qual o tipo da variável `chave`? Um `String`?

Comment: Você quer saber se existe um operador de XOR no SQL? Ou o que é `^=`?

Comment: @Mateus A chave é do tipo string sim.

Comment: @bigown gostaria de saber o que é, para entender melhor o código.
Mas já que comentou, fiquei com dúvida se existe no sql também.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Este é [operador de XOR](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/boolean-logical-operators?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397#logical-exclusive-or-operator-). No caso ele faz uma auto atribuição.

```
calculoChave ^= c;
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/3geH9H). E [no **.NET Fidlle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/hLHbp2). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Operator/Xor.cs).

é o mesmo que

```
calculoChave = calculoChave ^ c;
```

O [T-SQL possui o mesmo operador](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/bitwise-exclusive-or-transact-sql?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=sql-server-ver15). Até onde eu sei não possui a forma contraída mas agora você sabe como expandi-la.

Comment: Obrigado pela explicação. Consegui aqui.

Comment: Fiz uma conversão para a tabela ASCII, que é o resultado dessa expressão.

Comment: Gostaria de saber qual é o erro aqui para ter um -1?

Answer (score 10):

Somente completando a resposta do @Maniero, como você está fazendo um `foreach` sobre uma `String`, quer dizer que você está percorrendo caractere por caractere da `chave` e realizando um XOR entre o valor da variável `calculoChave` e o valor decimal do caractere atual, logo após o resultado é armazenado na própria variável `calculoChave`, por exemplo:

```
chave = "ab"
caractere "a"; decimal = 97; binário = 0110 0001
caractere "b"; decimal = 98; binário = 0110 0010
valor 0 (zero);              binário = 0000 0000
```

Ficaria assim:

```
1ª iteração
0000 0000   (00)  0       calculoChave
0110 0001   (97) 'a'      caractere atual
---------   (XOR)
0110 0001   (97) 'a'      calculoChave = 97

2ª iteração
0110 0001   (97) 'a'      calculoChave
0110 0010   (98) 'b'      caractere atual
---------   (XOR)
0000 0011   (03)          calculoChave = 3
```

Você pode verificar a [tabela ASCII](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) e olhar o valor decimal e binário de cada caractere, note que existe uma diferença entre o valor 0 (zero) e o caractere "0" (zero).